# What is the appropriate facet for a JSP tag library?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, taglib

I am converting some old Eclipse projects over to faceted form, and I'm uncertain which facets are appropriate for a JSP tag library (one Java class, one TLD file). "Dynamic Web Module" is overkill (generates a `WebContent/WEB-INF` and `WebContent/META-INF`, which are not needed for a tag library).

The web applications that use the tag library use Servlet Specification 3.1. The tag library conforms to `web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd`.

Is the standard practice here to simply use the "Java" facet?

Is there no additional facet that is appropriate for JSP Tag libraries?

The screenshot shows my current configuration, which works but feels like it is missing a facet.

Eclipse Mars, Java 1.8.0_60, Tomcat 8.0.26

[image: Available facets in Eclipse Mars]

Comment: Why would you need a runtime? It's a library. All you need is the ability to write Java code, the servlet and JSP API jar files as dependencies, and the ability to create a jar file containing your classes and xml files in it.

Comment: @JBNizet Correct, I've revised the question and screenshot.

Comment: If it's correct, then you have your answer: Java is the facet you're looking for. A JSP tag library is a jar file containing Java classes and XML files. You don't need anything more than the Java facet to do that.

Comment: I hope my answer helps you. I have written almost the same answer in a different way.

Comment: Thank you for the bounty!..:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think the comments have the answer to your question, I will try to
>   explain the same thing in a different way.  Keeping the project facet just to java is enough.

Facets are just the aspects for your IDE to interpret the project related configurations well. To develop a `JSP tag lib`, all you need is Tag Library Descriptor `youTag.tld` and the compiled `Java tag handler class` files used in your tag library. `Java project Facet` is enough to provide you all the helps needed for writing the `tag handler class`.

Your only worry may be to package it as a `jar` in the right way, his is explained well in the below link.

> Packaging the JSP Tag Library as `JAR` file is simple as per [the
>   official guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/taglib/admin.html#wp364493).